# lodash filter by single value and value in array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a quick and easy function that I need to use lodash for.

```
let obj = 

    {
        "AttributeID": "1",
        "KeyID": "0",
        "Value": "Undefined",
        "MetaInsertUtc": "2017-09-13T01:52:22.280"
    },
    {
        "AttributeID": "1",
        "KeyID": "1",
        "Value": "Tier 1",
        "MetaInsertUtc": "2017-09-13T01:52:22.280"
    }, {
        "AttributeID": "1",
        "KeyID": "2",
        "Value": "Tier 2",
        "MetaInsertUtc": "2017-09-13T01:52:22.280"
    }, {
        "AttributeID": "1",
        "KeyID": "3",
        "Value": "Tier 3",
        "MetaInsertUtc": "2017-09-13T01:52:22.280"
    }, {
        "AttributeID": "1",
        "KeyID": "4",
        "Value": "Tier 4",
        "MetaInsertUtc": "2017-09-13T01:52:22.280"
    }


let parent = 1;
let children = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];

let test = _.filter(obj, function(item) {
    return parseInt(item.AttributeID) === parent && parseInt(item.KeyID) IN[Children];
})
```

I am trying to filter my objects by a specific parent ID and within those results, find all those that have `KeyID` that are in our `children` array.

**Update:**

Here is my end result based on the selected answer. If there is a more shorthand way to do this by chaining some of these lodash methods together, let me know.

```
let valueObj = {
  "id" : "1",
  "name": "Joe"
},
{
  "id" : "2",
  "name": "Bob"
}
let selectedValues = _.map(valueObj, 'id');
let result = _.filter(obj, function(item) {
       return item.AttributeID === attributeID && _.includes(selectedValues, item.KeyID);
    });
```

Comment: Where are `[` and `]`???

Comment: `parseInt(item.KeyID) IN[Children];` try `children.indexOf(parseInt(item.KeyID)) > -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lodash#includes` method. If `children` array contains string values, you shouldn't convert `item.KeyID` to a number, just compare two strings:

```
let test = _.filter(obj, function(item) {
  let attrId = parseInt(item.AttributeID);
  return attrId === parent && _.includes(children, item.KeyID);
});
```

Comment: This seems right, just trying to fix another issue. I didn't realize my children array was an array of strings, I typed it correctly on the OP. Unrelated but is there a cleaner way to do this? `_.map(_.map(valueObj.data, 'id'), _.ary(parseInt, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `obj` is actually an array.

```
object.filter(item => {
  return parseInt(item['AttributeID']) === parent && children.indexOf(parseInt(item['AttributeID'])) > -1;
});
```

You can do this simple filtering in regular JS.